# how to replace the all the occurence using php

Tags: php

hi how to replace the all the occurrence of the spaces into `&nbsp;`, I am tying to save my message from editor to my db , while i retrieving the message it shows �� instead of spaces please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the problem with  tag in your head
replace your charset to ISO-8859-1

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of editor you used? In what application?

As I know maybe it has problem with the charset you used to display those message, and how did you retrieve those data from db?

For sure, try to peak into the db entry using PHPMyAdmin, or similar tools, and look if the messages you saved there also has ��. It it is, then it maybe problem on submitting, or collation you use on your db.